# Why can't I access and setState here?

Tags: reactjs

I have this handle change function. I cannot figure out why in the timeout section, I cannot access this.state?  It works if I do it outside of that?

The part where i'm trying to setState employment_level gives me an 'undefined' error.

The console log console.log(`${targetName}: ${targetValue}`); works perfecly... but the two that reference this.state.empoloyee and this.state.employment_level do not.

```
handleChange = e => {
    const targetName = e.target.name;
    const targetValue = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      [targetName]: targetValue,
    });
    if (this.state.editingTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.state.editingTimeout);
    }

    this.setState({
      editing: false,
      editingTimeout: setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(`${targetName}: ${targetValue}`);
        this.setState({
          employment_level: targetValue,
        });
          console.log(this.state.employee);
          console.log(this.state.employment_level);
      }, 300),
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it works if you use an arrow functions in:
`editingTimeout: setTimeout(() =>`